# NavigationView - ActionSheet - EdgesIgnoringSafeArea bug

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There's a weird UI bug in my View.

**Given:**

1. a NavigationView
2. an ActionSheet Along
3. with EdgesIgnoringSafeArea

**When:**

1. I scroll so that large NavBar becomes a inline NavBar
2. Show the ActionSheet
3. Scroll back to top

**Then:**

- The top nav bar view, loses its "EdgesIgnoringSafeArea" background.
- If while on top, if I show the actionSheet again, the view resolves
  the bug

Simple code to reproduce the bug:

```
   struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var shownSheet: ActionSheetType?

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    Color.red.frame(height: 1000)
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: self.barItem())
                    .actionSheet(item: self.$shownSheet, content: { sheetType in
                        switch sheetType {
                        case .add:
                            return ActionSheet(title: Text("Action Sheet"),
                                               buttons: [.cancel(Text("Cancel"))])
                        }
                    })
            }
        }

        private func barItem() -> some View {
            return Button(action: {
                self.shownSheet = .add
            }, label: {
                Text("actionSheet")
            })
        }

        private enum ActionSheetType: String, Identifiable {
            var id: String { rawValue }
            /// Add Button
            case add
        }
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

[image]

Thank you in advance!